# Is 到 in 他白到耀眼 a Coverb Or Just A Verb?

Tags: grammar, usage, adjectives, complement

When 到 comes after an adjective like 他白到耀眼, is the 到 a verb or a preposition? I know it means to the extent of.

Answer (score 3):

到 after an adjective is a degree particle that indicates "to what degree the adjective reaches"

Example:

[adjective] [degree] --> [白] [耀眼]

[adjective] [to the point of] [degree] --> [白] [到] [耀眼]

白[到]耀眼 = white [to the point of] dazzling

到 after a verb is a degree/result particle that indicates "to what degree the verb reaches" or "what resulted from the action"

Example:

- [verb] [to the point of] [degee]-->  [打] [到] [殘廢] ("to the degree of 殘廢" indicates the severity of the beating is higher than causing pain, but not to the point of causing death)
- [verb][result in][result]-->  [打] [到] [殘廢]("result in 殘廢" indicates the result of the beating)

打死 = verb + [result complement](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Result_complements) (打 is the verb, 死 is the result complement)

打殘 = verb + result complement (打 is the verb, 殘 is the result complement)

Answer (score 2):

> 到.... I know it means to the extent of.

Yes, you are almost there. My interpretation is:

他白**到**耀眼(的程度) - His whiteness (has **reached** the extent of) dazzling the eyes.

Answer (score 1):

他白到耀眼 = 他白**到**耀眼**的程度**

**到**什么**程度** is a popular structure (idiomatic usage or fixed collocation) in Chinese, which means **to the degree of** or **to the extent of**. Sometimes people omit the last part **的程度**.

In this structure,  **到** is a preposition for the noun **程度**, but the adjective 耀眼的 goes before the noun in Chinese.